# Running Executable File by just plugging the power of Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

My concern is "is it possible to run a executable file by just plugging the power of Raspberry Pi (any model)"? . Right now we`ll make a so called "ANNUNCIATOR", we will use the raspberry pi as our microcontroller and inside of it we will put the python code that will receive data from GPS and if the time matches on the schedule that the user input(s) the mp3 will play. It will be stand alone once the schedules is been scheduled so the user dont need the keyboard, monitor and mouse. by just plugging the power of raspberry pi, after the boot is it possible that the python executable file will run?

Comment: The easy way is to put a call to your executable in `/etc/rc.local`, although making it a "real" service may be a better idea (and with systemd it is really a breeze).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Raspberry PI, which has its own SE site (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: oh sorry i dont know that they have own topics guys.

Comment: thanks for the tip @MatteoItalia, i hope we can work together because im a newbie in raspberry pi :)

Comment: no big deal, probably a moderator will migrate the question soon. Best of luck with your Raspberry project. =)